# How to programmatically get the access token to send API call to Google Merchant Center (Google Shopping) with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-shopping-api, google-shopping

I recently get in touch with Google merchant product to sync all my website products into Google Merchant. When I follow the structure of the API documentation https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/quickstart
down to Authorization section I copy their library and copy the sample code to use. It actually work! However, when I doing testing to load that auth page it requires me to log in to the developer account for getting the access token and save it into session.

Is there any possibility that I can skip the login section to make it automatically then I can do corn system to run the sync (update products' details) hourly?

I tried to hardcore my account login API key into my code like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Sample Content API application');

//add my api key here
$client->setDeveloperKey(MY_API_KEY);

$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('YOUR_REDIRECT_URI');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content');
```

But it doesn't workЖ шt still requires me to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) for this.

> The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions such as those between a web application and a Google service. For this scenario you need a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved. This scenario is sometimes called "two-legged OAuth," or "2LO." (The related term "three-legged OAuth" refers to scenarios in which your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end users, and in which user consent is sometimes required.)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working example of authentication via **Service account** with PHP.

**PREREQUISITES**

1. Install the *"Content API for Shopping"* library which you can download [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). For installation see [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#installation).
2. Create your service account. [Here](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/guides/how-tos/service-accounts#steps-to-using-a-service-account-to-access-the-content-api-for-shopping) you will find the complete procedure.

At this point you will have obtained your **JSON file needed for authentication**.

As suggested by Google:

> **Important**: Protect the *.json key file that allows a service account
> to access the Google services for which it has been authorized. It is
> good practice to allow service accounts to only access one Google API
> each. This is a preventative measure to mitigate the amount of data an
> attacker can access in the situation that the service account’s *.json
> key file is compromised.

You can now use the following function to get the access token for the API call:

```
// gets access token for API call to Google Merchant Center
function gets_access_token_for_API_call() {

    // load the "Google APIs Client Library for PHP"
    require_once ( '/path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php' );

    // gets the JSON key of the service account
    $credentialsFilePath = '/path/to/merchant-center-123456789-987654321.json';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFilePath);
    $client->addScope( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content' );
    // fetches a fresh access token with a given assertion token.
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion(); // the deprecated alias: "refreshTokenWithAssertion()"
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();

    return $token;

}
```

The returned result will be an array similar to:

```
{
    "access_token": "1/8xbJqaOZXSUZbHLl5EOtu1pxz3fmmetKx9W8CV4t79M",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content"
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

*The code has been tested and works.*